# How to use orderby based on condition in Django?

Tags: django

I have a model called **DemoModel** and I am querying it i.e;

```
DemoModel.objects.all()
```

I am fetching all the objects but I want to do order_by based on condition i.e; In my models there is a field called **demo_field**,

If that field value is 'Testing' then it should be ordered using that condition.

```
DemoModel.objects.all().order_by(demo_field='Testing')
```

Is there anything like this? Or we have to create customized order_by?

Comment: You mean if any row has demo_field="Testing" then you need order that queryset right?

Comment: yes absolutely...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with **annotate**:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, IntegerField

result = DemoModel.objects.annotate(testing=Case(When(demo_field='Testing', then=1), default=0, output_field=IntegerField())).order_by('testing')
```

Comment: Really save my day!! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
result = DemoModel.objects.all()
if result.filter(demo_field="Testing").exists():
    result = result.order_by(demo_field)
return result
```